# Windows 10 search results appear in wrong language

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, language-pack

I just upgraded to Windows 10 from a German Windows 7 installation. I switched my display language to English (United States) and my region to English (United Kingdom). Now whenever I search for some settings like for example "UAC", the search results will still be in German.
[image: UAC search result]

Not only that, but the results of some other searches, such as "language" are not even clickable. The only option that can be clicked here is the one without a settings icon.
[image: language search result]

I already tried removing German completely in the language settings, switched between German and English as my display language several times and also rebuilt the search index.
Any solutions before I have to reinstall the OS entirely are appreciated.

Comment: Kind of a long shot, but did you completely blow away the search database prior to rebuilding the index? The file is C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Windows.edb and you will need to disable the indexing service before you're able to delete it.

Comment: @BrianC I didn't when I first rebuilt it but even doing so now didn't change anything unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Windows 7/8/10 system language - welcome screen, login, etc](http://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc)

Comment: I have the same problem afer installing the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, have you fond a working solution by now?

Comment: @bitbonk unfortunately I could not find a solution and after a few days I simply gave up and reinstalled the OS entirely

Comment: This thread may provide the solution http://superuser.com/questions/958279/windows-10-settings-not-indexed

Comment: Same problem after switching from Dutch to English with Windows 10. Search results come back in Dutch still, and they're note even clickable. Clearly a search index needs to be rebuilt, but none of the proposes solutions here work.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem (actually, my entire laptop was in Thai). I did the following steps:

To open *Settings*, go to the *Action Center* (the icon in the taskbar beside the clock) and press *All Settings*.

1. Go to *Settings* → *Time and Region* → *Region and Language* → Delete all other languages and only keep *English*. My keyboard layout was also Thai, so that can be changed here too.
2. *Control Panel* → *Region* → *Format* → Set it to *English*
3. *Control Panel* → *Region* → *Location* → Set it properly
4. *Control Panel* → *Region* → *Administrative* → *Change system locale* → Select *English*

This was the most important step. You may reboot after this.

5. *Control Panel* → *Region* → *Administrative* → *Copy settings* → Check both boxes and click *OK*

Again reboot! After doing all this German should vanish entirely from your laptop. After this, make sure you have deleted German language and selected override English as language everywhere just to be sure.

Comment: Tried this and deleting `Windows.edb` but the problem is still there, the results still show up in the old language and are not clickable.

Comment: Did you install anniversary update? If not, please do, since my problem of unclickability was solved by it

Comment: I'm on version 1607, which I believe is the anniversary update and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this myself. Try rebuilding the 'index', this is where the start-menu searchresults are stored.

http://www.winbeta.org/news/how-rebuilding-your-search-index-windows-10

Comment: After I rebuild the 'index' the search still appear the wrong language. But I tryed logout cortana first, then rebuild the index, and login into cortana again finally it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure the following [guide](https://techdirectarchive.com/2023/02/01/how-to-change-regional-settings-for-all-users-on-windows-11/) will help those of you that are still experiencing this issue on Windows 11.

The Windows Regional format refers to the way in which date, time, currency, and other numeric values are displayed on a running Windows operating system. The Regional format settings specify the date, time, and number formats used by the operating system, as well as the language used for messages and system alerts. The Regional format settings are determined by the country or region that you select in the Windows settings. This information is used by Windows and other applications to display information in a format that is appropriate for the selected country or region.

https://techdirectarchive.com/2023/02/01/how-to-change-regional-settings-for-all-users-on-windows-11/

Answer (score -3):

When you change the language in Windows not all the nooks and crannies of the OS are affected. I haven't run into your problem before, but I would try copying the language setting to other parts of Windows. Here's how.

1. In the Cortana box type C*ontrol Panel*.
2. Select the heading *Clock, Language, Region*.
3. Under the Region heading select *Change location*.
4. A Wizard dialog will open, click on the *Administrative* tab and press the *Copy Settings* button.
5. On the wizard page fill the two checkboxes at the bottom of the page and click *OK*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I actually did that already since I wanted to change the language for the welcome screen as well but I forgot to mention it in my post