# Incorrect language in search results

Tags: windows-10, search, language

I recently bought a new laptop (HP Omen) and after setting it up, changed the primary language to English (originally Dutch) and entered a key for Windows 10 Pro (Home was installed by default).

After rebooting the laptop to complete the changes, everything looks English except for search results. When I search for a setting, the results are still in Dutch. Furthermore, clicking on any of these results doesn't do anything.

[image: screenshot]

I already checked my language settings as suggested by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1113596/482177), and rebuilt the search index as suggested by [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1123296/482177).

Searching for anything other than control panel items seems to work just fine.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you.