# After changing system language in windows 10, search shortcuts in start menu stopped working

Tags: windows, windows-10, language

I recently changed my system language from danish to english. Now when I f.ex. want to access my Bluetooth settings, I open the start menu and start to type bluetooth. The Bluetooth settings link in the search results still appear in danish, and does not work. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you already try to [rebuild the search index](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/58569-rebuild-search-index-windows-10-a.html)?

Comment: No, but I just tried, and that didn't work

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Someone else had a very similar problem, and after a few days of trying they simply did a full Windows 10 reinstall.  However, a few months later another person posted an answer that has earned several up-votes, so hopefully it will work for you, too.  If so, we can mark this one as a "duplicate" and consider ourselves lucky:  [Windows 10 search results appear in wrong language](https://superuser.com/questions/1051410/windows-10-search-results-appear-in-wrong-language/1113596).

Comment: That didn't work as well, but it seems to be the same issue. I hope the Creative Update will fix this...

Comment: I found this answer: https://superuser.com/a/972410/713463 - and the folder %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState  under Settings/Indexed only contains a da-DK folder, and not a en-UK folder. However I have no access to a en-UK folder, so can't replace it...

Comment: Ended up reinstalling windows - it works properly now...

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but it sounds like others resorted to a Windows reload, also.