# Windows 10 Start menu: "These results may be incomplete", won't find settings

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, multiple-users

When searching in the Start menu of Windows 10, the results usually include items from the System Settings app. On a fresh install of Windows 10 Enterprise, either 1607 or 1511, this works as expected for the first user to logon.

After going through Windows update and creating a second local user (or, if joined to a domain, using a domain user to logon), Search doesn't work for this user. Results will *not* include any items from System settings.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/958279/windows-10-settings-not-indexed) question already proposes a lot of troubleshooting of which I already tried everything. Maybe the most interesting thing is that the folder `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState` stays empty, while the same folder is populated with files in the first user's profile. Copying those files over makes search work, however, this is more of a workaround than an actual solution.

This might be related to a recent update, because both 1511 and 1607 without any updates installed are behaving correctly. I'm also using the German version of Windows, however, changing Language packs did not change search behaviour.

Comment: This sounds like a classic case of a group policy being applied to a user and not the machine, which in my experience, is applied only after the user logs in twice.

Comment: I thought so too, but this is also happening on a machine that is not connected to any network at all (i.e. an isolated VM). gpresult on domain joined computers is also basically empty.

Comment: You mention domain user though...

Comment: I clarified this in the original post. This is reproducible (for me) on any machine running Win 10 Enterprise 1511 or 1607.