# Windows 10 Search not working for settings (after changing user folder name). Indexed folder missing

Tags: windows-10, search

After changing my user folder name because of 1 foreign letter, Windows 10 settings wouldn't appear in taskbar search anymore. But the old search UI for control panel works for all the "oldschool" settings.

Second account search for settings works but it also is missing the indexed folder??

I tried every solution I could find without any effect:

1. Index rebuild
2. Index troubleshoot that found "search not working" then "fixed" it, but nothing changed.
3. Cmd script ResetWindowsSearchBox

But I couldn't try the solution with the indexed folder settings,  because I don't have it. As seen here - [Windows 10 Settings not indexed](https://superuser.com/questions/958279/windows-10-settings-not-indexed),
Not even on the other user account where the search is working for settings.
(Hidden files and folder settings is showing).

Windows 10 Pro version 20H2 with latest updates.
Build 19042.804

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Did you ensure the new `%UserProfile%` path is actually selected to be indexed? Rebuilding the index does not occur instantaneously, as it only rebuilds when the PC is idle since it's resource-intensive _(you can force it to rebuild while the PC isn't idle, but will experience some sluggishness)_ - have you verified the index was fully rebuilt?

Comment: The other user cannot scan the folder due to permissions. That is default behavior. Changing the folder is never a good thing, these are one of the weird issues that can happen. It is recommended to create a new user, and migrate your settings and files over to that account instead. In your case, you would have to undo your changes first.

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this problem.

Check `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy\SettingsConstraintIndex` location in registry. In my case the previous folder name was used to define the path for search index files, so I had to update information.

The links below provide more information.

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-settings-search-no-results-found-fix/

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/search-does-not-work-inside-windows-10-settings/7a702a1c-2b0b-4a73-89c9-9e2455975ae5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).