# Windows 10 search: can't open Control Panel items

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, control-panel

**Update**

I've mentioned this in the comment already, but it's worth repeating here to avoid any misunderstanding: this **issue is gone** after numerous Windows updates. This means that unfortunately I won't be able to test/accept proposed solutions. Hopefully your comments will help someone else, though, so thank you for writing them!

**Original issue**

I've upgraded to Windows 10 Pro and have a strange issue with Windows Search: whenever a search result is a Control Panel item (e.g. "Administrative Tools", "Mouse", "Sound" etc.; and I'm talking about the old style Control Panel, not the new better looking Settings window) I can't open them with a click/enter!
This issue also applies to a few other setting items not directly visible in the Control Panel (e.g. Disk Management settings such as "Create and format hard disk partitions").

Other search results are functioning just fine: I can open apps, files, Control Panel itself, settings exclusive to the new Settings window, e.g. "Pen and Touch" (it's a guess re exclusive, since when a setting item is available in both old Control Panel and new Settings, I can't open it), etc.

I can use the settings themselves just fine, but I have to first open the Control Panel itself, which is rather annoying.

Comment: Just tested this again after numerous Windows updates and this issue is no longer there. Still have no clue as to why it was there to begin with.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  The biggest change since I noticed the control panel items not working is I installed the Anniversary Update.  At first I thought it was just the sound control, but after some further testing, it seems to be every (or at least most) old fashioned control.

Comment: @MBraedley Did you already try `SFC /SCANNOW` from an elevated command prompt? You might also try running [cpl_file_assoc](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/fileassoc/xp_cpl_file_assoc.zip) and then rebooting afterwards and then seeing if you still have the issue. As a last resort, you could try [resetting Windows 10](http://www.zerodollartips.com/reset-windows-10-pc-using-reset-this-pc-windows-10/)

Comment: I tried that command, and it wouldn't run successfully (I was in an elevated command prompt).  I'll try the file association thing in the morning.

Comment: @MBraedley Be sure to look into [resetting Windows 10](http://www.zerodollartips.com/reset-windows-10-pc-using-reset-this-pc-windows-10/) as well if you need to and it's applicable.

Comment: What went wrong with sfc /scannow ? A problem with sfc normally means a problem with Windows itself.

Comment: This is an issue of linking the UI to the actual actions; it can get damaged by the following: some .net framework forced versions, some V++ libraries, some KB dll updates in combination with the above. the nV video driver in combination with specific Physx drivers and the above. Usually, if you update to the latest .net and have the OS patches up to date the issue should be gone. Practically, when in doubt, update windows, the video driver and the .net framework and you should be 100% fine.

Comment: @harrymc The error I was getting was it didn't have permission to run (or something to that extent).  I don't remember exactly what the message was, as I've just reverted to per-Anniversary Update, which seems to have fixed things.  I may try applying the Anniversary Update again (which TBQH, didn't exactly go as smoothly as it should have the first time), since I like a bunch of the features in it.

Comment: Better to not install via Windows Update - use [In-place Upgrade](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: @harrymc: Windows Update had tried and failed earlier in the month, so I downloaded the update for offline install.  Maybe I'll wait until the next build becomes available.

Comment: Do you have multiple languages installed (even US and UK english)? Is Cortana enabled? Did you run any of the privacy protection applications that are available for Windows 10 (non official / disable telemetry apps)?

Comment: Besides describing how Windows Update fails, try the methods in the article [5 Tips to Fix Windows Store and App Issues in Windows 10](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-tips-fix-windows-store-app-issues-windows-10/).

Comment: @Argonauts Yes, I have US and either Canadian or UK English installed, and Cortana is enabled.

Comment: Any answer to my above comment ?

Comment: @harrymc: No, I've settled, for the time being, on not applying the Anniversary Update.  I have a feeling that I'll have to start from a clean slate at some point in the not too distant future.

Comment: Try in-place upgrade (offline install) before clean install, as you will keep your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fair amount of evidence that adding or removing additional languages in windows 10 can break search capabilities, specifically including control panel items not showing up in searches.

Since you are using multiple languages, this seems to line up well with your issues. The theory is that different components of Windows search end up with different language settings which (it gets less clear here) breaks things.

The fixes offered up are fairly consistent:

1. Remove all languages besides English.
2. Rebuild the search indexes.

To remove installed languages run the following command in an elevated command prompt and follow the prompts:

```
 Lpksetup /u
```

Then rebuild the indexes:

> From Indexing Options, Advanced Options, click Rebuild to begin
>   reindexing. Then restart Windows.

Sources:

[superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/958006/how-can-i-make-windows-10-search-my-settings-control-panel-items)
[superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/958279/windows-10-settings-not-indexed/961510#961510)
[tenforums](http://www.tenforums.com/general-support/35445-settings-search-results-arent-quite-ready-yet-uk-us-ok.html)

Comment: Search isn't the problem, and I don't think it was for the original asker either.  The problem is that I couldn't open most old style control panel dialogs.

Comment: Considering the common ground your situation/ issue has with the links I provided its probably worth it to at least try the language removal. Is it probably your issue? Probably not. But its more likely than anything else that's been tried thus far.

Comment: No, the search is a red herring.  Ignore it.

Comment: 3 languages installed during anniversary upgrade; similar area of problems. Suit yourself. You should probably ask this as a new question as a 'fielded' solution to the opening question is so far wrong as not to merit trying. Its a bit confusing. The mods could likely move the bounty if you opened a new question ( I'm guessing).

Comment: There is a solution that seems to work for most users over here: http://superuser.com/questions/950102/what-do-i-have-to-index-in-order-to-search-the-windows-control-panel-in-win10/1182041#1182041