# In Windows 10's Settings app, typing anything into "Find a setting" gives me no results

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

If I open up the Setting app/program in Windows 10, there is a search bar on the top right with the words "Find a setting" in it.

No matter what I type in that box, I get "No results for " and the string I typed.

Also, in the start menu, if I type a setting name ("resolution" in this example) I get the proper results in the Start Menu search results(e.g. "Change the screen resolution") but, when I click that result, I get a blank Settings box with no results inside and my search word is in the "Find a setting" box.

What did I break? Can someone help me "unbreak" it?

Comment: The accepted answer in this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/958006/how-can-i-make-windows-10-search-my-settings-control-panel-items?rq=1  solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

From this thread: [How can I make Windows 10 search my settings/control panel items?](https://superuser.com/questions/958006/how-can-i-make-windows-10-search-my-settings-control-panel-items?rq=1)

The answer from TranslucentCloud solved my issue.

1) Stop Windows Search service

2) Remove the "SystemIndex" key from   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\CrawlScopeManager\Windows\

(note, I had to change the ownership of the key to delete it)

3) Start the Windows Search service