# Windows 10 Creator's Update How to Search Control Panel

Tags: windows-10, search, windows-10-v1703, windows-desktop-search

Since the Creator's Update in Windows 10, I have been unable to search items in the Control Panel from the Start Menu. I waited for a long time in the hopes that it would resolve itself. It has not. I have followed the instructions here: [What do I have to index in order to search the Windows Control Panel (in Win10)?](https://superuser.com/questions/950102/what-do-i-have-to-index-in-order-to-search-the-windows-control-panel-in-win10) and on many other related posts because they seemed to have a similar issue. These solutions have not resolved the issue, however. I believe Windows 10 Creator's Update removed Control Panel's items from being indexed.

Note that, regarding Solution 2 in the top answer to my link, my directory %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState is completely empty.

I do not have multiple languages enabled, so that shouldn't be an issue. This de-indexing has occurred on both my Windows 10 PCs that updated to the Creator's Update. I can still search for Control Panel, but the individual items inside are not available (such as Programs & Features). This is very problematic as Settings has far fewer options than Control Panel.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like reinstalling Windows is in order because how you search the control panel has not changed.  Alternative is to install a third-part Windows 10 start-menu replacement.

Comment: Well, I believe I tried that. I installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 on a new hard drive for one of my computers, and that was after Creator's Update released. I don't think that would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the search function. Why it was removed from the popup on a right click is maddening.

Right click START and in SEACRH enter control panel. It will appear in a list. Not a real solution for the tool as it need to be brought back to normal accessibility.